# Error while uploading the IPA to App Store

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, app-store, ipa

I have archive my project and exported the IPA successfully using xcode,but when I upload the ipa to the App store through Application Loader I getting below error.

I know error is because of the IOS SDK version .Can anyone help me how to update the ios SDK version 10 in my current xcode.What are the prerequisite need to generate the ipa (Mac OS version,SDK version,Xcode version etc).

xcode Version 8.2.1 
Mac Os version 10.12

Below is the error got while upload ipa through application loader

[image]

Thanks in Advance

Comment: You need to get Xcode 9 or newer, That will be the easiest option.

Comment: Whether it will support my mac os version,I have downloaded xcode 10 and it ask for mac os version 10.13

Comment: You must upgrade to macOS 10.13 and install Xcode 9 (or Xcode 10 since that is now the latest)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting from 1 April-2018, apple stopped accepting the apps which are build with iOS SDK lower than 11.0.

**As per article on 15 Feb, 2018:**

> From starting in April of 2018, all new apps submitted to the App Store must be built using the iOS 11 SDK, which is included in Xcode 9 or later.
>
> [For more detail](https://www.macrumors.com/2018/02/15/new-apps-ios-11-sdk-april/)

**Latest news on 12 Sept:**

> Starting March 2019, all new apps and app updates for iPhone, including universal apps, will need to be built with the iOS 12 SDK and support iPhone XS Max.
>
> [For more detail](https://developer.apple.com/news/)

**What to do now?**

You have to download the Xcode 9.0 or later which have iOS SDK version greater than 11.0 and build with your IPA with the new Xcode.( My suggestion is to use Xcode 9.3, as installing Xcode 10 will need upgrading your system as well. Also there can be some extra work to be done as Xcode 10 have support for iOS 12 as well.)